# Why is JS not targeting my classes seperatly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a portfolio website nearly completed, I just need the JS to slide In the divs that are positioned above the containers to display some extra info and a button to view the work in a new page. I had it working but it was displaying all the info on every piece of work instead of on one single piece of work. Now when I tried to debug it I have made it stop completely. Any help would go along way, it has been a very stressful morning already.

I have tried the CSS method of hover tags but much prefer the JS scripting way. It was somewhat working until I tried fixing my error and now I can't wrap my head around why it won't do anything since I have referred back to the original code I used.

```js
$(".work_hub").mouseover(function() {
  $(".work_hover_info").slideUp();
});
$(".work_hub").mouseleave(function() {
  $(".work_hover_info").slideDown();
});
```

```css
.movement_hover {
  margin-top: 913px;
}

.movement_hover1 {
  margin-top: calc(912.5px * 2);
}

.movement_hover2 {
  margin-top: calc(912.5px * 3);
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.work_container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.work_hover_info {
  background: #000000;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .7;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 260px;
  right: 200px;
  z-index: 1000;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.work_hover_title {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
}

.work_hover_description {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.work_hover_button {
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 350px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 70px 70px 70px 70px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 70px 70px 70px 70px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

.work_hover_button:hover {
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 350px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 70px 70px 70px 70px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 70px 70px 70px 70px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.view_work {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.work_title {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.work_hub {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 20px 36px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 20px 36px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34);
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 36px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="work_container">
      <div>
        <div class="work_hover_info">
          <h1 class="work_hover_title">Placement Title</h1>
          <h2 class="work_hover_description">Write some info about the piece and why you designd this piece</h2>
          <div class="work_hover_button">
            <h2 class="view_work">View</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h1 class="work_title">Logo Visualisation</h1>
        <img class="work_hub" src="../assets/work-one.png" height="auto" width="800" alt="Work Image">
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="work_hover_info movement_hover">
          <h1 class="work_hover_title">Placement Title</h1>
          <h2 class="work_hover_description">Write some info about the piece and why you designd this piece</h2>
          <div class="work_hover_button">
            <h2 class="view_work">View</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h1 class="work_title">Rock Banner</h1>
        <img class="work_hub" src="../assets/work-two.png" height="auto" width="800" alt="Work Image">
        <div>
          <div class="work_hover_info movement_hover1">
            <h1 class="work_hover_title">Placement Title</h1>
            <h2 class="work_hover_description">Write some info about the piece and why you designd this piece</h2>
            <div class="work_hover_button">
              <h2 class="view_work">View</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h1 class="work_title">Forest Fire</h1>
          <img class="work_hub" src="../assets/work-three.png" height="auto" width="800" alt="Work Image">
          <div>
            <div class="work_hover_info movement_hover2">
              <h1 class="work_hover_title">Placement Title</h1>
              <h2 class="work_hover_description">Write some info about the piece and why you designd this piece</h2>
              <div class="work_hover_button">
                <h2 class="view_work">View</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <h1 class="work_title">Beach Body</h1>
            <img class="work_hub" src="../assets/work-four.png" height="auto" width="800" alt="Work Image">!-->
          </div>
        </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Why would it ever target your classes "separately"? You are targeting ALL elements with `work_hub` class to slide EVERY element with `work_hub_info` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are having a problem is due to a simple misunderstanding of how jQuery (not JS) works. My first time was exactly like this, and once I figured it out, it made a lot of  things easier.

**Your Current JS:**

```
$(".work_hub").mouseover(function() {
  $(".work_hover_info").slideDown();
});
$(".work_hub").mouseleave(function() {
  $(".work_hover_info").slideUp();
});
```

`$()` works by getting a list of ***all*** html elements that fit whatever is in the `()`. So, appropriately, you want all of your `.work_hubs` to have the mouseover function. The problem here is that in the mouseover function, you `$(".work_hover_info")`. Remember, it gets ***all*** `.work_hover_info`. This is why it expands all of them. Luckily, this is easily fixed. You just have to limit the results... What you really want is just the `.work_hover_info` of the `.work_hub` that is being hovered.

**On Events Listeners:**

The mouseover function is called an event listener. One nice thing about event listeners in jQuery is that you can know which element is firing with the special word `this`. But `this` is simply an element and doesn't give you the cool jQuery functions. You can always stick `this` in a jQuery like so: `$(this)` and now do some cool jQuerying with it. And this is where the other answers come into play.

```
// Wait until the document is ready...
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add a listener to all .work_hubs
  $(".work_hub").mouseover(function() {
    // Find MY .work_hover_info and tell it to slide down.
    $(this).siblings( ".work_hover_info" ).slideDown();
  });

// Add another listener to all .work_hubs
  $(".work_hub").mouseleave(function() {
    // Find MY .work_hover_info and tell it to slide down.
    $(this).siblings( ".work_hover_info" ).slideUp();
  });
});
```

The key here is the use of `$()`, `this` (the work_hub being hovered),  and `.siblings()`. Since each `.work_hub` only has one `.work_hover_info`, looking for it in siblings works perfectly. so, `$(this).siblings('.work_hover_info')`:

1. gets a jQuery version of the element that fired the event
2. Gets all siblings of that element that are `.work_hover_info`

Then it fires the appropriate method on all of them. But since you only have one per `<div>`, it all works out. Here is a [fully working example](https://jsfiddle.net/v4xb07k3/) using only your html and css code with the adjusted js. You'll have to scroll left or expand the result box to see it.

Comment: Note: `this` is only the element that fired the event in event listeners. In other contexts `this` can mean lots of other things.

Comment: This works 90% of what I want. When I hover over the .work_hover_info it scrolls up which I understand is how it works but I tried adding the .work_hover_info class to the function and it just scrolled down and no longer rolled up when I left the div. That is a small issue that I can try to wrap my head around, another issue is that the .work_hover_info div slides down from the top of the page, instead of from the .work_hub which are hovered over. How would I set it to slide down from the top of the work, and not the top of the page?

Comment: Most of what you are mentioning is related to positioning, which is not a js thing *(or rather, it can be, but shouldn't be)*. You generally need to look at CSS for that. Would I be correct in assuming that you are relatively new to web ui programming?

Comment: I am not new to HTML and CSS, I did it in college and I do freelance jobs now. It's just for this project, which is my own, I am using JS for movement. Normally all my sites are static and only move based on media queries. So trying to set this up so that when new work is added it moves accordingly is new to me. So yeah, your somewhat correct that am new this type of web design.

Comment: I would look at CSS position rule. It's important to understand that absolute works a little differently depending upon the positioning type of its ancestors. There are several great answers that can explain the intricacies. They're outside the scope of this question, so it wouldn't be proper to add them to this question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Script

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".work_hub").mouseover(function() {
      $(this).siblings( ".work_hover_info" ).slideUp();
     });
    $(".work_hub").mouseleave(function() {
         $(this).siblings( ".work_hover_info" ).slideDown();
     };
   });
  });
```

Comment: Didn't affect it at all, I am still trying to wrap my head around it, in theory, at least for me, this should work, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Add this below script:  and you have make a mistake in you script only.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".work_hub").mouseenter(function() {
        $(".work_hover_info").slideDown();
    });
    $(".work_hub").mouseleave(function() {
        $(".work_hover_info").slideUp();
    });
});
```

You script Mistake below:

```
   $(".work_hub").mouseleave(function() {
         $(this).siblings( ".work_hover_info" ).slideDown();
     };
   });
```

Above your script you have add extra close sign on third line which I have show you above...  " };"  remove this..